# How to Combine between a list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x

For example here is the list

```
[('please', 'a'), ('answer', 'b'), ('this', 'a'), ('question', 'd'), ('thankyou', 'f')]
```

Now I need to combine when the second element in the tuple is the same

The expected output is

```
please this
```

Because the second element of both `please` and `this` is `a` .So that needs to be combined.

Comment: What happens if there are also multiple instances of 'b' being repeated? Like ` [('please','a'),('answer','b'),('this','a'),('question','d'),('thankyou','b')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict


l = [('please','a'),('answer','b'),('this','a'),('question','d'),('thankyou','f')]

frequencies = defaultdict(list)

for word, key in l:
  frequencies[key].append(word)

output = ' '.join([words for (key, words) in frequencies.items() if len(words) > 1][0])

print(output)

# prints "please this"
```

[repl.it link](https://repl.it/@rakenodiax/WelloffBulkyPriority)

Answer (score 1):

One can do it using defaultdict :

```
from collections import defaultdict

input_list = [('please', 'a'), ('answer', 'b'), ('this', 'a'), ('question', 'd'), ('thankyou', 'f')]
output_list = defaultdict(list)

for x, y in input_list: 
    output_list[y].append(x)
```

The output_list.values() will have the required result as:

```
dict_values([['please', 'this'], ['answer'], ['question'], ['thankyou']])
```